# passing javascript variable in document.getElementbyID

Tags: javascript

I know this is a silly question but i am not able to get the required result.I want to assign a javascript variable `bck` in `document.getElementById(bck)` .Everything is working fine i.e. alert displaying the correct value of variable bck but when i am using it inside the `document.getElementbyID` i am getting the following error:

```
document.getElementById(bck) is null
```

I googled it and looked in SO relevant topics also but got nothing helpful.
the value of `backdropcontent[m][1]` is Reden,also the value of `selectedbg` is Reden.

```
     <script>
     for ( var m=0;m<backdropcontent.length;m++) {
     if(selectedbg==backdropcontent[m][1]){
     var bck=backdropcontent[m][1]+'div1';
     alert(bck);
     document.getElementById(bck).style.display = "block";
         document.getElementById(bck).style.top = "0px";

    }
  }
    </script>
```

html part:

```
 <div class="mcdropdown" id="Redendiv1" style="display:none;position:relative">
                    <a  style="cursor: default !important">
                    <input type="text" name="reden1" id="reden1"  style="background-image: url('<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site; ?>/templates/performitor/images/123.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;height:14px;width:130px !important;color:#BDBDBD;border: 1px solid #8e9daa;" disabled="disabled" value="Totaal"  autocomplete="off"/>
                    </a>
                  </div>
```

please note that i dont want to alter the structure of my code so please dont suggest any major change.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: @Sniffer can you please elaborate.i know we can assign a variable in document.getElementbyid but what i am doing wrong that the varible is not getting parsed.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to tell what is wrong. We don't know what `backdropcontent` is or what the HTML looks like.

Comment: what is bck - String ?

Comment: @Quentin why html part is important when i have given u a full working javascript code?

Comment: i am not sure just give try and provide a space in 'div1' to ' div1' see it helps or not

Comment: @RishabhRaj — because the JavaScript is trying to manipulate the DOM that the HTML creates.

Comment: @Quentin i updated my question with html part

Comment: @RishabhRaj: Don't tell us a preview come up with full story. So, where is your HTML code....?

Comment: Any result? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19857626/1636522

Comment: @wared no wared but thanks for reply.

Comment: I mean, do you still get the same error?

Comment: yes i am getting the same error

Comment: Are you definitely sure that `alert(bck);` shows existing ids?

Answer (score 0):

The element with id *backdropcontent[m][1]+'div1'*, does not exist

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing error mostly because your element doesn't exist on the page yet. Move your `<script>` block below your code or use  `window.onload event`.

```
window.onload = function(){
//your code
}
```

Or using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// your code
});
```

Answer (score -3):

you use the code in the following pattern

```
     <script>
     for ( var m=0;m<backdropcontent.length;m++) {
     if(selectedbg==backdropcontent[m][1]){
     var bck=backdropcontent[m][1]+'div1';
     alert(bck);
      document.getElementById("bck");.style.display = "block";
         document.getElementById(bck).style.top = "0px";

    }
  }
    </script>
```

May be this code helps you.

Comment: You've used a string where the question is explicitly wanting to use a variable and have introduced syntax errors!